# clearInterval not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I have the following bit of code which is used to rattle divs.

I use clearInterval to stop the rattling but it doesn't appear to work.

Any idea why please?

```
squares = $('.' + square_class); 
var rattle; 

 rattle = setInterval(function() {
 squares.delay(2000).effect('shake', { times:4, distance: 5 }, 100);
 }, 2000);

clearInterval(rattle);
```

Comment: "does not appear to work" means what exactly? In your code sample nothing should happen, as the `setInterval` is cleared before it is executed for the first time.

Comment: Did you close the parentheses after setInterval?

Comment: sorry, by does not work, i mean that the div continues to rattle after clearInterval(rattle) is called

Comment: This smells of a scoping error

Comment: the code sample is edited for brevity containing only the pertinent points

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see this set up. If it is not, please tell us

```
<script>
var rattle;

window.onload=function () {

  rattle = setInterval(
    function() {
      squares.delay(2000).effect('shake', { times:4, distance: 5 }, 100); 
    }, 
  2000);

  setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(rattle); },10000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code..you should fix it like this:

```
var rattle = setInterval(function(){
    squares.delay(2000).effect('shake', { times:4, distance: 5 }, 100);
}, 1500);
```

And then

```
clearInterval( rattle );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actual animation effect to stop without going through it's full duration use jQuery `stop()` method

```
clearInterval(rattle);
squares.stop();
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/stop/